# In NUnit how do I specify tolerance for struct's properties comparison?

Tags: c#, struct, nunit, equality

I have the following NUnit tests, where for some reason comparison of structs fails:

```
public struct Record
{
    public double P1 { get; set; }
    public double P2 { get; set; }
}

[TestFixture]
public class UnitTest
{
    [Test]
    public void PassingTest()
    {
        Assert.That(100, Is.EqualTo(99.99999999).Within(.0001));
    }

    [Test]
    public void FailingTest()
    {
        Assert.That(new Record { P1 = 1.0, P2 = 100 },
            Is.EqualTo(new Record { P1 = 1.0, P2 = 99.99999999 }).Within(.0001));
    }

    [Test]
    public void AlsoPassesTest()
    {
        Assert.That(new Record { P1 = 1.0, P2 = 100 },
            Is.EqualTo(new Record { P1 = 1.0, P2 = 100 }).Within(.0001));
    }
}
```

Question (1): Why does the test with structs comparison fail? Question (2): If the test with structs comparison fails because tolerance is not "deeply" applied, how can I setup things so that test with structs comparison passes?

Comment: There was no hope this could have worked in the form you described it. To NUnit, it is more or less like `Assert.That(new object(), Is.EqualTo(new object()).Within(.0001));`. How would NUnit know what it means for a user-defined type like your `Record` to be "within" `.0001` of another `Record`?

Comment: Well, it could have used reflection to see what properies are in struct and then compare those with tolerance...

Comment: Strongly related: [How can I use NUnit's EqualTo().Within() constraint with a custom data type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31752407/)

Comment: Note that `Record` as it stands above is a _mutable struct_ which is considered "evil" by many (though not all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to write this by hand, it seems. Something like this:

```
static class IsAlternatively
{
  public static AlternativeEqualConstraint EqualTo(Record r)
  {
    return new AlternativeEqualConstraint(r);
  }
}

class AlternativeEqualConstraint : NUnit.Framework.Constraints.Constraint
{
  readonly Record expected;
  double tolerance;

  public AlternativeEqualConstraint(Record r)
  {
    this.expected = r;
  }

  public AlternativeEqualConstraint Within(double tolerance)
  {
    this.tolerance = tolerance;
    return this;
  }


  public override bool Matches(object obj)
  {
    actual = obj;

    if (!(obj is Record))
      return false;

    var other = (Record)obj;

    return Math.Abs(other.P1 - expected.P1) < tolerance && Math.Abs(other.P2 - expected.P2) < tolerance;
  }

  public override void WriteDescriptionTo(NUnit.Framework.Constraints.MessageWriter writer)
  {
    writer.WriteExpectedValue(expected);
    writer.WriteMessageLine("Expected within tolerance '{0}'.", tolerance);
  }

  public override void WriteActualValueTo(NUnit.Framework.Constraints.MessageWriter writer)
  {
    writer.WriteActualValue(actual);
  }
}
```

Use it like this, of course:

```
  Assert.That(new Record { P1 = 1.0, P2 = 100.0, },
    IsAlternatively.EqualTo(new Record { P1 = 1.0, P2 = 99.99999999, }).Within(.0001)
    );

  Assert.That(new Record { P1 = 1.0, P2 = 100.0, },
    IsAlternatively.EqualTo(new Record { P1 = 1.0, P2 = 100.0, }).Within(.0001)
    );

  Assert.That(new Record { P1 = 1.0, P2 = 100.0, },
    IsAlternatively.EqualTo(new Record { P1 = 1.0, P2 = 66.6, }).Within(.0001)
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make two separate assertions for struct's properties:

```
[Test]
public void FailingTestSoonToPass()
{
    var recordToTest = new Record { P1 = 1.0, P2 = 100 };
    var recordToCompareWith = new Record { P1 = 1.0, P2 = 99.99999999 };
    Assert.That(recordToTest.P1, Is.EqualTo(recordToCompareWith.P1)recordToCompareWith.P1);
    Assert.That(recordToTest.P2, Is.EqualTo(recordToCompareWith.P2).Within(.0001));
}
```

I think that Tolerance is not applied to whole struct as you set it on a struct as whole.

Anyway, depending on the nature of your tests, you can consider splitting this test into two separate ones, especially if only one of the properties has to have a tolerance and the other one needs to be exact.